# Applying for two position at the same department

Tags: job

There are two advertised positions at one department. The department is approx. 30 people. So it is not a large institution where my two applications would be "lost". I am sure if I apply for both positions it will end up at the same people/commitee.

Both position are for scientific staff, not for postdoc. The two positions are quite similar but there are some differences. I think I match one position more than the second one. *Should I apply only to one position or can I apply for both? The application has to be done through online submission system, i.e. it is not possible just write to the cover letter that I am eventually interested in both positions.*

Comment: Does it say who posted it? Is it in the same group

Comment: I saw you edited - I mean are these both to be employees of the same person? If they are both to work for Prof X I would offer different advice if they were for two different groups in the same dept

Comment: @Azor Ahai it is not listed who will be the supervisor. Only the department is listed.

Comment: Hmm, without more details, it's hard to say. I would err on only one application

Comment: @GoodDeeds I think it does not answer my question. The institution can be huge where people will be not familiar that you apply for several jobs, or can be small and "everybody" will know that you are applying to two positions. My case is a small department where the committee will see that I am applying to two very similar jobs.